# Непонятная логика в аккордеоне

Tags: javascript, html5

В моём понимании при нажатии первой полосы должно быть:

1. Присваивание класса .active и окрашивание в зелёный цвет.
2. Выпадение соответствующего сообщения из первой полосы.

А получается иначе:

1. Присваивание класса .active и окрашивание в зелёный цвет. - ЭТО СРАБАТЫВАЕТ
2. Выпадение соответствующего сообщения из первой полосы. - ЭТО СРАБАТЫВАЕТ ТОЛЬКО ПОСЛЕ ПОВТОРНОГО НАЖАТИЯ.

Почему 2-ой этап срабатывает только после повторного нажатия? Мне не нужна правильная реализация - она есть на [www.w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp). Мне нужно объяснение, почему не срабатывает `if(panel.style.display === 'none')`, после которого, по логике вещей, реализуется `panel.style.display = 'block';` и сообщение должно появляться сразу же, но появляется со второго раза.

```js
let acc = document.getElementsByTagName('h3');

for (let i=0; i < acc.length;i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
    this.classList.toggle('active');
    let panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if(panel.style.display === 'none'){
      panel.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
      panel.style.display = 'none';
    }
  })
};
```

```css
h3 {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
h3:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}
p {
  display: none;
  border: 1px dashed #000;
}
.active, .accordion:hover {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
 <h3>Accordion #1</h3>
 <p>Know about UX and the User-Centered Design (UCD) Process
Learn how to create the golden thread between your product and the user
Use reliable UX methodologies to create an effective UX strategy
Bring your UX strategy to life with wireframes and prototypes
Set measurable metrics and conduct user tests to improve digital products</p>
 <h3>Accordion #2</h3>
 <p>Know about UX and the User-Centered Design (UCD) Process
Learn how to create the golden thread between your product and the user
Use reliable UX methodologies to create an effective UX strategy
Bring your UX strategy to life with wireframes and prototypes
Set measurable metrics and conduct user tests to improve digital products</p>
 <h3>Accordion #3</h3>
 <p>Know about UX and the User-Centered Design (UCD) Process
Learn how to create the golden thread between your product and the user
Use reliable UX methodologies to create an effective UX strategy
Bring your UX strategy to life with wireframes and prototypes
Set measurable metrics and conduct user tests to improve digital products</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для ответа на ваш вопрос надо воспользоваться дебагом.

Причина в том, что у вас `panel.style.display` при первом нажатии пустое. Потому что вы скрываете его с помощью `css`.

Если хотите узнать, какое значение стиля у элемента в данный момент времени можете воспользоваться [getComputedStyle](https://learn.javascript.ru/styles-and-classes).

Код, который показывает ошибку:

```js
let acc = document.getElementsByTagName('h3');

for (let i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('active');
    let panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    console.log('Значение panel.style.display = ', panel.style.display);
    if (panel.style.display === 'none') {
      panel.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      panel.style.display = 'none';
    }
  })
};
```

```css
h3 {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

h3:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}

p {
  display: none;
  border: 1px dashed #000;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<h3>Accordion #1</h3>
<p>Know about UX and the User-Centered Design (UCD) Process Learn how to create the golden thread between your product and the user Use reliable UX methodologies to create an effective UX strategy Bring your UX strategy to life with wireframes and prototypes
  Set measurable metrics and conduct user tests to improve digital products</p>
<h3>Accordion #2</h3>
<p>Know about UX and the User-Centered Design (UCD) Process Learn how to create the golden thread between your product and the user Use reliable UX methodologies to create an effective UX strategy Bring your UX strategy to life with wireframes and prototypes
  Set measurable metrics and conduct user tests to improve digital products</p>
<h3>Accordion #3</h3>
<p>Know about UX and the User-Centered Design (UCD) Process Learn how to create the golden thread between your product and the user Use reliable UX methodologies to create an effective UX strategy Bring your UX strategy to life with wireframes and prototypes
  Set measurable metrics and conduct user tests to improve digital products</p>
```

Вот как можно сделать, используя `getComputedStyle`.

```js
let acc = document.getElementsByTagName('h3');

for (let i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('active');
    let panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    var styleDisplay = getComputedStyle(panel).display; // вычисляем текущие свойства
    console.log('Значение panel.style.display = ', styleDisplay);
    if (styleDisplay === 'none') {
      panel.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      panel.style.display = 'none';
    }
  })
};
```

```css
h3 {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

h3:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}

p {
  display: none;
  border: 1px dashed #000;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<h3>Accordion #1</h3>
<p>Know about UX and the User-Centered Design (UCD) Process Learn how to create the golden thread between your product and the user Use reliable UX methodologies to create an effective UX strategy Bring your UX strategy to life with wireframes and prototypes
  Set measurable metrics and conduct user tests to improve digital products</p>
<h3>Accordion #2</h3>
<p>Know about UX and the User-Centered Design (UCD) Process Learn how to create the golden thread between your product and the user Use reliable UX methodologies to create an effective UX strategy Bring your UX strategy to life with wireframes and prototypes
  Set measurable metrics and conduct user tests to improve digital products</p>
<h3>Accordion #3</h3>
<p>Know about UX and the User-Centered Design (UCD) Process Learn how to create the golden thread between your product and the user Use reliable UX methodologies to create an effective UX strategy Bring your UX strategy to life with wireframes and prototypes
  Set measurable metrics and conduct user tests to improve digital products</p>
```

Comment: А ваш пример рабочий?

Comment: @Arsen нет, не рабочий. Автор не просил делать ему рабочий пример, он просил объяснить, почему не работает.

Comment: Ну тогда зачем копировать не рабочий код в ответ? можно отредактировать его  так(как предлагаете) чтобы данный код был рабочий?

Comment: @Arsen Я код специально не редактировал, что бы была видна ошибка. Если я его отредактирую, как показать ошибку? Хотя, я придумал)

Comment: Просто нет смысла копировать тот же код(не рабочий), вот уже отредактированный ответ будет более понятным автору ))

Comment: @Arsen Смысл копировать нерабочий код - что бы показать ошибку в неработающем коде!

Comment: > копировать нерабочий код - что бы показать ошибку в неработающем коде |  где же логика? Если автор не в состоянии найти проблему в своём нерабочем коде, с чего вы взяли что после копирования вами того же  кода он может найти ошибку? Другое дело, что после моего комментария, вы отредактировали данный "нерабочий код" так, что автор  уже может понять смысл вашего ответа...

Comment: @Arsen Я нерабочий код не редактировал. Я его оставил, написал комментарий, где ошибка, показал, как эту ошибку найти. Я добавил новый работающий код. Расскажите, как вы будете показывать ошибку в исправленном, работающем коде?

Comment: - а вы в курсе что обманывать это не есть хорошо? )) в самом начале вы просто скопировали код, только после моего первого комментария вы отредактировали свой ответ и добавили  console.log('Значение panel.style.display = ', panel.style.display); что конечно в свою очередь помогло автору понять где проблема... Видимо мы с разных планет, удачи))

Comment: @Arsen а вы в курсе, что надо сначала вникнуть в детали, подумать, а потом уже действовать? Сначала объявление переменной у ТС не заметили, теперь не можете правильно посмотреть список правок. В моем первом варианте был `console.log`. Во второй правке я добавил туда текст с пояснением. Посмотрите внимааааательно. А потом уже пишите.